# Why the output is converted to float in println?

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
int x = 5;
System.out.println((x>5)?2.3:2); // OP-> 2.0
System.out.println((x==5)?10:20);// OP-> 10
```

why in 1st case, the OP converted to 2.0 from 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(x>5)?2.3:2` since you are returning **2.3** or **2**.

They should be from the same type. (Since the return type *should be the same*)

Since `2.3` is double, `2` is converted to double.

If you change for example to:

`(x>5)?1:2`

Then the output will be `2`. Since both are integers and no cast needs to be done.

Writing it with `if` will look like this:

```
if(x > 5) 
   return 2.3
else
   return 2
```

If the return type of the method that includes this code is `int` you'll get an error.

But if it's double, then you're OK, since `2` will be cast to `2.0`.

Read about the [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have the ternary operator `?:`: `(x>5) ? 2.3 : 2`
This operator has exactly one return type - which must match both cases -> therefore return type `float` for `2.3`

Answer (score 0):

In the [Java Language Specification 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) you can see why it is happening. The ternary operator has a type. In this concrete case, the second and third operands have types that are convertible to numeric types, so [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) is applied.